# Does com.day.cq.search.impl.SimpleSearchImpl expose an addPredicate() method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, search, content-management-system, aem

I need to filter some pages so that they won't appear in search.
For that there is a method called

```
addPredicate(new Predicate("mytype", "type").set("group.4_group.1_property", "jcr:content/cq:template"));
```

This method is not present in `com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Search`.  I'm not sure in which API this `addPredicate` method is present.

In the CQ5 docs, it is said that this method is implemented in `SimpleSearchImpl`, which is present in the package `com.day.cq.search.impl.SimpleSearchImpl`.  However, when I try to import that package, it throws an error saying that package is invalid.

If `SimpleSearchImpl` is not the required class for `addPredicate` method, can you please tell me what is the class that is needed for the method `addPredicate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.day.cq.search.SimpleSearch` interface is exported from the `cq-search` bundle, but not the `com.day.cq.search.impl.SimpleSearchImpl` implementation class.

You can see a list of the exported packages here:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/com.day.cq.cq-search
```

You can get a reference to a SimpleSearch implementation by [adapting a Resource](http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/wem/developing/sling-adapters.html) or using a [SCR reference](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html).

Alex Klimetschek gave a great presentation on [using the QueryBuilder API]http://www.slideshare.net/alexkli/cq5-querybuilder-adapttoberlin-2011) as an alternative to the SimpleSearch approach, this might be useful for helping to understand predicates.